# Component work locally, but not deployed

Tags: angular

I have this component.

```
import {Component} from "angular2/core";
import {ClothesService}  from "./clothes.service";

import {AngularFire} from 'angularfire2';
import {Inject} from "angular2/core";
import {FirebaseRef} from 'angularfire2';
import {SideNav} from './sidenav';

@Component({
    selector: "today",
    templateUrl: "app/html/today.component.html",
    providers: [ClothesService],
    directives: [SideNav]
})


export class TodayComponent implements OnInit {
    constructor(@Inject(ClothesService) _clothesService: ClothesService, @Inject(FirebaseRef) ref: Firebase) {
        if (!ref.getAuth()) {
            window.location.href="https://randohinn.com/wearnator-app/";
        }
        console.log(this);

        _clothesService.getClothes(ref).then(function(result) {
            console.log(result);
            if (!result) {
                window.location.href = "clothes-list";
            }
        });
        console.log(this);
    }

    openNav() {
        document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.width = "250px";
        $('.overlay').css("visibility", "visible");
    }

    closeNav() {
        document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.width = "0";
        $('.overlay').css("visibility", "hidden");

    }




}
```

And HTML for it

```
<div class="row">
    <header class="col-xs-12 center">
        <i class="fa fa-history header-left-action"></i>
        <div class="header-title">Today</div>
        <i (click)="openNav()" class="fa fa-ellipsis-v header-right-action"></i>

    </header>
</div>
<SideNav></SideNav>
```

This works fine locally, but when I upload it to [the app site](https://randohinn.com/wearnator-app), whenever I try to call `openNav()` from the HTML part in a click, 
it errors, saying openNav is not a function. What could this be? The resulting js has the openNav function in it.

This is the resulting js.

```
System.register(["angular2/core", "./clothes.service", 'angularfire2', './sidenav'], function(exports_1, context_1) {
    "use strict";
    var __moduleName = context_1 && context_1.id;
    var __decorate = (this && this.__decorate) || function (decorators, target, key, desc) {
        var c = arguments.length, r = c < 3 ? target : desc === null ? desc = Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(target, key) : desc, d;
        if (typeof Reflect === "object" && typeof Reflect.decorate === "function") r = Reflect.decorate(decorators, target, key, desc);
        else for (var i = decorators.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) if (d = decorators[i]) r = (c < 3 ? d(r) : c > 3 ? d(target, key, r) : d(target, key)) || r;
        return c > 3 && r && Object.defineProperty(target, key, r), r;
    };
    var __metadata = (this && this.__metadata) || function (k, v) {
        if (typeof Reflect === "object" && typeof Reflect.metadata === "function") return Reflect.metadata(k, v);
    };
    var __param = (this && this.__param) || function (paramIndex, decorator) {
        return function (target, key) { decorator(target, key, paramIndex); }
    };
    var core_1, clothes_service_1, core_2, angularfire2_1, sidenav_1;
    var TodayComponent;
    return {
        setters:[
            function (core_1_1) {
                core_1 = core_1_1;
                core_2 = core_1_1;
            },
            function (clothes_service_1_1) {
                clothes_service_1 = clothes_service_1_1;
            },
            function (angularfire2_1_1) {
                angularfire2_1 = angularfire2_1_1;
            },
            function (sidenav_1_1) {
                sidenav_1 = sidenav_1_1;
            }],
        execute: function() {
            TodayComponent = (function () {
                function TodayComponent(_clothesService, ref) {
                    if (!ref.getAuth()) {
                        window.location.href = "https://randohinn.com/wearnator-app/";
                    }
                    console.log(this);
                    _clothesService.getClothes(ref).then(function (result) {
                        console.log(result);
                        if (!result) {
                            window.location.href = "clothes-list";
                        }
                    });
                    console.log(this);
                }
                TodayComponent.prototype.openNav = function () {
                    document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.width = "250px";
                    $('.overlay').css("visibility", "visible");
                };
                TodayComponent.prototype.closeNav = function () {
                    document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.width = "0";
                    $('.overlay').css("visibility", "hidden");
                };
                TodayComponent = __decorate([
                    core_1.Component({
                        selector: "today",
                        templateUrl: "app/html/today.component.html",
                        providers: [clothes_service_1.ClothesService],
                        directives: [sidenav_1.SideNav]
                    }),
                    __param(0, core_2.Inject(clothes_service_1.ClothesService)),
                    __param(1, core_2.Inject(angularfire2_1.FirebaseRef)), 
                    __metadata('design:paramtypes', [clothes_service_1.ClothesService, Object])
                ], TodayComponent);
                return TodayComponent;
            }());
            exports_1("TodayComponent", TodayComponent);
        }
    }
});
//# sourceMappingURL=today.component.js.map
```

And for reference, this component works fine on both local and uploaded

```
import {Component} from "angular2/core";
import {ClothesService}  from "./clothes.service";
import {Cloth} from "./cloth";
import {AngularFire} from 'angularfire2';
import {Inject} from "angular2/core";
import {FirebaseRef} from 'angularfire2';
import {Rating} from './rating';
import {SideNav} from './sidenav';

@Component({
    selector: "today",
    templateUrl: "app/html/additem.component.html",
    providers: [ClothesService],
    directives: [Rating, SideNav]
})


export class AddItemComponent implements OnInit {
    private rate: number = 3;
    private photo: String;
    private newItem: Cloth
    private usersClothes: Array;
    private user: String;
    private refer: Firebase;

    constructor(private _clothesService: ClothesService, @Inject(FirebaseRef) ref: Firebase) {
        if (!ref.getAuth()) {
            window.location.href="https://randohinn.com/wearnator-app/";
        }
        var t = this;
        _clothesService.getClothes(ref).then(function(result) {
            if (result == null || result == undefined) {
                t.usersClothes = new Array();
            } else {
                t.usersClothes = result;
            }
        });
        this.user = ref.getAuth().uid;
        this.refer = ref;
    }

    ngOnInit() {
        var t = this;
        $(document).ready(function() {
          $.cloudinary.config( { cloud_name: "wearnator"});
            $("#selectedFile").unsigned_cloudinary_upload("af8fvvkw",{ cloud_name: 'wearnator' });
            $('#selectedFile').bind('cloudinarydone', function(e, data) {
                t.photo= data.result.url;
                $('.browseB').css("background-image","url("+t.photo+")");
            });
        });

    }

    onUpdate(value) {
        this.rate = value;
    }

    openNav() {
        document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.width = "250px";
        $('.overlay').css("visibility", "visible");
    }

    closeNav() {
        document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.width = "0";
        $('.overlay').css("visibility", "hidden");

    }

    onSave(name: String, type: String) {
        this.newItem = new Cloth(name, type, this.photo, this.rate);
        console.log(this.newItem);
        this.usersClothes.push(this.newItem);
        this.refer.child("clothes").child(this.user).set(this.usersClothes);
        console.log(this.usersClothes);
        window.location.href="/clothes-list";
    }
}
```

Comment: Sounds like an issue with minification.

Comment: Yeah. Anything I can do to fix it, though?

Comment: Don't minify ;-) As far as I know it's broken but I don't know details because I don't use TS myself https://github.com/angular/angular/search?q=minified&state=open&type=Issues&utf8=%E2%9C%93

Comment: Hmm, I'm actually not minifying at all. edited OP with resulting JS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I figured it out myself. turned out to be FTP doing something weird witht the uploads not always overriding.